# Does there exist an analytic function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{H}$? Here $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I am learning complex analysis on my own. I want to understand the solution of the following problem.

Does there exist an analytic function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{H}$? Here $\mathbb{H}$  is the upper half plane.

I found that Picard's Little Theorem, which says that if an analytic function omits two points, then $f$ is constant.

I have attempted the problem using Picard's  Little Theorem.  Since $f(\mathbb{C}) \subset \mathbb{H}$, then $0,1 \not\in f(\mathbb{C})$, hence $f$ is constant.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: Simpler argument would be to notice that if $f$ does not take a value in a disk $D(z_0,R)$ then $g(z) = 1/(f(z)-R)$ is analytic on $C$ and bounded. And then to prove that analytic and bounded functions must be constant. This last claim follows directly from Cauchy formula on Taylor's coefficients of $f(z)$.

Comment: Echoing @Salcio comment, adding that the assertion that bounded entire functions are constant is "Liouville's theorem", if one wants keywords...